# jQuery Mobile Change body background image on page change

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have the following scenario, two pages with different body id. This is for setting a different background on each body. However when I navigate to page2 from page1 the background keeps being the same. Is there a way to set a background image on page change ??

PAGE1:

```
HTML:
<body>
   ...html content
</body>
```

PAGE 2:

```
HTML:
<body id="myOtherBg" >
   ...html content
</body>
```

CSS:

```
 body{
        background: url(../img/background_white.png) center center no-repeat;
    }

    #myOtherBg{
        background: url(../img/background_white.png) center center no-repeat;
    }
```

This works on a normal page load, but when reaching the page2 from page1 using jquerymobile the background doesn't change.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: `body` remains the same as Ajax loads page2's div only into DOM. If you want to disable Ajax, add `data-ajax="false"` or `rel="external"` to anchor.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving page1's body tag an id and target that in your first rule. So instead of `body{...}`, make it `#firstBG{...}`. That way page2 does not even attempt to pull the first page's background.

Comment: Your page2 is still showing the background for page1?

Comment: you changed the code from: body{...} to #firstBG{...}? If you inspect using F12, and examine the body tag on the first page, you can see what CSS Rule is being applied to the right.

Comment: yes of course, loading the pages statically works, but when navigating using jquerymobile from  page1 to page2 the background doesn't change. I guess its related to the ajax way that jquery mobile navigate pages, however I can't disable this ajax navigation due to the project requirements.

Comment: Can you add some javascript to page2 that fires when the page loads? If so, maybe you can change the background via jQuery as soon as page2 loads.